# update line based on previous line

Tags: awk, solaris, csv

I have a issue since I'm not familiar with awk. I have csv file generated from sar -d output converted to csv style:

```
12:33:41        unix,restarts
12:35:00,lofi4096,0,0.0,0,0,0.0,0.0
,iscsi0,0,0.0,0,0,0.0,0.0
,scsi_vhc,0,0.0,0,0,0.0,0.0
,nfs1,0,0.0,0,0,0.0,0.0

12:45:00,lofi4096,0,0.0,0,0,0.0,0.0
,iscsi0,0,0.0,0,0,0.0,0.0
,scsi_vhc,0,0.0,0,0,0.0,0.0
,nfs1,0,0.0,0,0,0.0,0.0
```

and I want to convert to this

```
12:33:41        unix,restarts
12:35:00,lofi4096,0,0.0,0,0,0.0,0.0
12:35:00,iscsi0,0,0.0,0,0,0.0,0.0
12:35:00,scsi_vhc,0,0.0,0,0,0.0,0.0
12:35:00,nfs1,0,0.0,0,0,0.0,0.0

12:45:00,lofi4096,0,0.0,0,0,0.0,0.0
12:45:00,iscsi0,0,0.0,0,0,0.0,0.0
12:45:00,scsi_vhc,0,0.0,0,0,0.0,0.0
12:45:00,nfs1,0,0.0,0,0,0.0,0.0
```

My attempt but since awk reads line by line I don't know out to keep the previous line value. I would expect that what I have should work. Any idea how I can obtain my desired result. I tried with awk, but I guess this should be possible with sed or the hard way with a custom shell script ( I'm trying to avoid doing this part ).

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN {
        FS=",";
}
{
        print $1
        if ($1 != "") {
                mydate=$1;
                print $0;
        }
        else {
                print $mydate","$0;
        }
}
```

Running the system with Solaris 11.1.

Comment: A lot of awk issues lately...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It gets a bit long as you seem to have blank lines in the input.  The following might work for you:

```
awk -F'[, ]' '{if (NF!=0 && $1=="") {$1=prev} prev=$1}1' OFS=, inputfile
```

The idea is to split fields on `,` and whitespace (the latter in order to handle the first line of input).  Check if the first field is blank **and** the number of fields is not zero (handle blank lines), then replace the first field with the previously stored first field.

For your input, it'd produce:

```
12:33:41        unix,restarts
12:35:00,lofi4096,0,0.0,0,0,0.0,0.0
12:35:00,iscsi0,0,0.0,0,0,0.0,0.0
12:35:00,scsi_vhc,0,0.0,0,0,0.0,0.0
12:35:00,nfs1,0,0.0,0,0,0.0,0.0

12:45:00,lofi4096,0,0.0,0,0,0.0,0.0
12:45:00,iscsi0,0,0.0,0,0,0.0,0.0
12:45:00,scsi_vhc,0,0.0,0,0,0.0,0.0
12:45:00,nfs1,0,0.0,0,0,0.0,0.0
```

Comment: works like a charm, just in Solaris 11 it has to be the gawk ( it stands for gnu awk ). thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

With `sed`:

```
sed '/^[0-9]/{               # if line starts with digit
h                            # overwrite hold buffer with pattern space content
s/\([^,]*\),.*/\1/           # extract timestamp
x                            # exchange: put the original line back into pattern
}                            # space and the timestamp in hold space
/^,/{                        # if line starts with a comma
G                            # append hold space (timestamp) to pattern space
s/\(.*\)\n\(.*\)/\2\1/       # swap the initial line content and the timestamp 
}' infile
```

in one line:

```
sed -e'/^[0-9]/{h;s/\([^,]*\),.*/\1/;x' -e\} -e'/^,/{G;s/\(.*\)\n\(.*\)/\2\1/' -e\} infile
```

Answer (score 1):

Another `sed`:

```
sed '$!N;/\n,/s/\([^,]*\).*\n/&\1/;P;D' <in >out
```

For each input line which is `!` not the `$` last, `sed` will append the `N`ext input line to pattern space as preceded by a `\n`ewline character. It will then attempt a `s///`ubstitution which involves copying the first possible group of `^,` not-comma characters to the space just preceding a comma which immediately follows a `\n`ewline. If it cannot do so, well, no harm done, I guess.

`sed` will then `P`rint up to the first `\n`ewline in pattern space and `D`elete same before beginning the cycle anew from the top with the next pair of input lines.

#### OUTPUT

```
12:33:41        unix,restarts
12:35:00,lofi4096,0,0.0,0,0,0.0,0.0
12:35:00,iscsi0,0,0.0,0,0,0.0,0.0
12:35:00,scsi_vhc,0,0.0,0,0,0.0,0.0
12:35:00,nfs1,0,0.0,0,0,0.0,0.0

12:45:00,lofi4096,0,0.0,0,0,0.0,0.0
12:45:00,iscsi0,0,0.0,0,0,0.0,0.0
12:45:00,scsi_vhc,0,0.0,0,0,0.0,0.0
12:45:00,nfs1,0,0.0,0,0,0.0,0.0
```